# Работа с несколькими процессорами (не ядрами)

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, процессор

Есть какое-то большое .Net приложение-служба, которая делает очень много повторяющихся вычислений,
вычисления объемные, но не суть важно. Главное их очень много.
Ну и мы начали использовать многопоточный код и действительно увидели очень сильный прирост производительности.

Поставили это дело клиентам, они счастливы, все хорошо. У них мощный сервак с процессором на 24 ядра, почти все эти ядра
мы задействуем.
И вот проходит время, клиенты говорят НУЖНО БОЛЬШЕ ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬНОСТИ.
И меняют сервак, на котором появляются ДВА ПРОЦЕССОРА по 24 ядра у каждого. Код нашего .net приложения не менялся.

В итоге, стало работать раза в 3-4 хуже и медленнее. Но стоит только физически отключить ОДИН процессор, и все начинает
работать так же быстро.

И вот вопрос, может кто сталкивался.
Как в таком случае мне правильно распределять нагрузку уже не по ядрам (это работает вроде), а по процессорам?

Comment: Я прошу прощение... НО не лучше будет использовать в таком случае 1cpu но вычисления проводить в GPU? К примеру с помощью CUDA Если использовать Nvidia. 24 ядра на одном cpu против 768 ядер на самой дишманской 1050ti. А на 1080ti уже целых 3584 ядер CUDA.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вроде, на кол-во процессоров программе пофигу. Сама ОС рулит потоками и планирует их на разных процессорах. Т.е по идее, деградации производительности быть не должно. А не может быть проблемы в чем-то другом? Например, из-за большого кол-во ядер вы стали использовать слишком много ОЗУ => сервер начинает тупить. Например, вы считали какие-то мега-коллекции по 1 гб на ядро, что в сумме давало 24 гб, которые были, а теперь вы используете 48 гб, которых нет=> подкачка и пробуксовка...

Comment: Ну или из-за такого большого кол-ва ядер вы начали выполнять много работы и уперлись в IO-операции... В общем, мне кажется, что дело в чем-то другом.

Comment: @АртурФранк не корректно сравнивать вычислительный юнит видео карты и ядро центрального процессора точнее их кол-во. они по-разному устроены, работают. я за массово параллельные вычисления, но для этого еще и задача должна хорошо ложиться на gpu(параллелиться)

Comment: а межпроцессных взаимодействий много в программе?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ТС говорит, что код не переписывал=> ОС сама рулит тем, на каких процах запускать потоки.

Comment: Возьмите профайлер, и посмотрите, где именно приложение стало проводить больше времени. Без кода и без возможности воспроизвести проблему, все ответы будут даны практически наугад.

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но все же:

Программе все равно на кол-во процессоров, так как это задача ОС. Именно она планирует на каком ядре какого процессора запустить поток.

Мне видится, проблема в том, что повысив одну характеристику ПК не была повышена другая характеристика ПК.

Например, вы гоняли большие коллекции в многопоточном режиме по 1 гигу на поток и вы расходовали 24 гб памяти(24 ядра), которые имелись на ПК. Теперь вы расходуете 48 гигов, хотя на ПК всего 28 гигов => подкачка и все плохо.

Так же проблема может быть в том, что вы уперлись в IO-операции- сетка не справляется, бд погибает.

В общем, проблема может быть не в процессорах и нужно выполнить профайлинг. Посмотреть в монитор ресурсов, например.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже что это не то. что можно решить изнутри программы. В общем и целом OS будет влиять на скедлинг потоков.

На что можно обратить внимание:

1) Могут ли потоки быть логически завязаны один на второй? То есть могут ли они ждать один другого в любой промежуток времени.
Хорошая идея что бы проверить виновата программа или настройки операционной системы - написать программу, которая запускает кучу потоков которые вообще не связаны между собой и просто делают пустое действие(пустой цикл раз на пару секунд). И проверить может ли нагрузка CPU перевалить за 50%. Если может - значит у тебя интерлок потоков. Если не может - значит виноваты настройки операционки.

2) Есть 2 версии .NET runtime, и ты можешь использовать не ту которую нужно. Вот урывочек статьи с MSDN:

> .NET Framework applications designated for deployment on multiprocessor machines, such as those using the Intel Xeon MP processors, should make use of the server-optimized runtime implementation (MSCorSvr.dll). This version of the runtime has a modified garbage collector that splits the managed heap into several sections, with one per CPU. Each CPU has its own garbage-collection thread, so they can all participate simultaneously in the collection cycle. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dndotnet/html/dotnetperftechs.asp)

Ответ основан на: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21013405/Multi-Processor-using-with-C-for-max-performance.html

Comment: Повлиять можно. Есть WinAPI SetAffinity(точное название не помню...) или что-то в этом роде. Можно жестко привязато поток к конкретному ядру. Но это делать не рекомендуется.

Comment: Вас ис «скедлинг»? Нихт ферштейн.

Comment: @ixSci - очевидно, scheduling - планирование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov очевидно, это когда написано по-русски (либо же по-английски), а не это издевательство как над русским, так и над английским языком.

Comment: Я забыл перевод на русский и зная что меня поймут и так :) Это было проще чем лезть в переводчик)